# Https redirect error

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have an SSL certificate for website `http://xyz.co/`.

I created `.htacces` file for forcing users to use **https** instead of http.

I tried:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But it shows me error as

`net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect to an entirely different url to make sure your condition is actually firing. At first sight I would say your `RewriteRule` is wrong because that's no RegEx, `^` is just an anchor.

So try this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

I assume you don't get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` errors when you remove this part.

Comment: So I should have this: `RewriteRule  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: No, there's no pattern at all now. Check the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)